# How to alter a column's data type in a PostgreSQL table?

Tags: sql, postgresql, psql, alter-table, alter-column

Entering the following command into a PostgreSQL interactive terminal results in an error:

```
ALTER TABLE tbl_name ALTER COLUMN col_name varchar (11);
```

What is the correct command to alter the data type of a column?

Answer (score 432, accepted):

See documentation here: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-altertable.html

```
ALTER TABLE tbl_name ALTER COLUMN col_name TYPE varchar (11);
```

Comment: For some other cases, you might need to specify the way to cast like `ALTER TABLE tbl_name ALTER COLUMN col_name TYPE integer USING col_name::integer;`

Comment: @Nobu why do we have to do this in `some cases` and what are those cases?

Comment: @Darth.Vader you might need to do this when there is data already existing in the column that can't be cast automatically.

Comment: Another example for casting: I had a jsonb column with existing data that I needed to convert to text.

Comment: in some cases you might also need to combine the cast with `nullif` expression, particularly if you've already had a record with a null value on the field/column that you're looking to change. In my case, i was trying to change the column type from `varchar` to `uuid`, but i have null value in the field that i'd like to change. So i got an invalid input syntax error. To resolve the situation i combine the alter statement with a `nullif` expression such follow:
`alter table user alter column branch_id type uuid using (nullif(branch_id,''))::uuid;`

Comment: it's worth mentioning you may want to cast twice in some cases as follows `col_name::text::real;`

Answer (score 67):

If data already exists in the column you should do:

```sql
ALTER TABLE tbl_name ALTER COLUMN col_name TYPE integer USING (NULLIF(col_name, '')::integer);
```

As pointed out by @nobu and @jonathan-porter in the comments to @derek-kromm's answer, somewhat cryptically.

Comment: What about if the column was a NUMERIC with a DEFAULT value. How do you remove or change the default values

Answer (score 19):

Cool @derek-kromm, Your answer is accepted and correct, But I am wondering if we need to `alter` more than the column. Here is how we can do.

```
ALTER TABLE tbl_name 
ALTER COLUMN col_name TYPE varchar (11), 
ALTER COLUMN col_name2 TYPE varchar (11),
ALTER COLUMN col_name3 TYPE varchar (11);
```

[Documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-altertable.html)

Cheers!! Read Simple Write Simple