# Npgsql.PostgresException: Column cannot be cast automatically to type bytea

Tags: entity-framework, npgsql, ef-core-2.1

Using EF-Core for PostgresSQL, I have an entity with a field of type `byte` but decided to change it to type `byte[]`. But when I do migrations, on applying the migration file generated, it threw the following exception:

> Npgsql.PostgresException (0x80004005): 42804: column "Logo" cannot be
>   cast automatically to type bytea

I have searched the internet for a solution but all I saw were similar problems with other datatypes and not byte array. Please help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The error says exactly what is happening... In some cases PostgreSQL allows for column type changes (e.g. `int` -> `bigint`), but in many cases where such a change is non-trivial or potentially destructive, it refuses to do so *automatically*. In this specific case, this happens because Npgsql maps your CLR byte field as PostgreSQL `smallint` (a 2-byte field), since PostgreSQL lacks a 1-byte data field. So PostgreSQL refuses to cast from `smallint` to `bytea`, which makes sense.

However, you can still do a migration by writing the data conversion yourself, from `smallint` to `bytea`. To do so, edit the generated migration, find the `ALTER COLUMN ... ALTER TYPE` statement and add a `USING` clause. [As the PostgreSQL docs say](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-altertable.html), this allows you to provide the new value for the column based on the existing column (or even other columns). Specifically for converting an int (or smallint) to a bytea, use the following:

```
ALTER TABLE tab ALTER COLUMN col TYPE BYTEA USING set_bytea(E'0', 0, col);
```

If your existing column happens to contain more than a single byte (should not be an issue for you), it should get truncated. Obviously test the data coming out of this carefully.

Comment: Thanks for your response. My apologies for my late response. I'm confused as to where to put that line of SQL command in the migration file. This is what I have in the `up` method of the migration file.  

`migrationBuilder.AlterColumn<byte[]>(
                name: "Logo",
                table: "Companies",
                nullable: true,
                oldClrType: typeof(byte),
                oldNullable: true);`

Comment: Try replacing that line with a call to `migrationBuilder.Sql("...")`, placing my proposed `ALTER TABLE` above in the parameter. For a complete solution you'd have to do the reverse for the down method - casting bytea to smallint - which can be truly destructive as later bytes are dropped.

Comment: And of course, test thoroughly on some dev environment before running this on an actual production database.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. Although I had to reset migrations and used a fresh database to continue my work, I made a backup and will try your solution on it. I'm grateful.

Answer (score 1):

Although the answer given by @Shay Rojansky is correct, I encountered some difficulties when trying to apply it as described above. I had to adjust it a bit to make it work for me:

Let say we have an entity like this:

```
public class Service
{
    public long Id { get; set; }

    public string? Name { get; set; }

    public string? Image { get; set; }
}
```

And you decided to change the type of "Image" from "string" to "byte[]" (or from "byte" to "byte[]") and created your migrations after the changes. PostgreSQL will throw an exception stating that "column cannot be automatically converted to type bytea"

As @Shay Rojansky already pointed out, you should go through your migrations file to find something like the following:

```
migrationBuilder.AlterColumn<byte[]>(
    name: "Image",
    table: "Services",
    type: "bytea",
    nullable: true,
    oldClrType: typeof(string),
    oldType: "text");
```

If you find it, you need to replace it with:

```
migrationBuilder.Sql(@"ALTER TABLE ""Services"" ALTER COLUMN ""Image"" TYPE BYTEA USING ""Image""::bytea");
```

I used the [verbatim string literal](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/strings/) to escape special characters so that the resulting string is the following in pure SQL:

```
ALTER TABLE "Services" ALTER COLUMN "Image" TYPE BYTEA USING "Image"::bytea;
```

For more details, please see these pages:

- https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-tutorial/postgresql-change-column-type/
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.migrations.migrationbuilder.altercolumn?view=efcore-8.0
- [How to alter a column's data type in a PostgreSQL table?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7162903/how-to-alter-a-columns-data-type-in-a-postgresql-table)