# Getting "sqlite3.OperationalError: near "ALTER": syntax error" when modifying datatype of a column

Tags: python, sqlite, alter, sqlite3-python

Our group is tasked to create and modify SQL tables (we chose to do it in Python) including the `ALTER` command but when we try to alter dataype of a column `Job_id` from `CHAR (10)` to `VARCHAR (10)`, we always get this syntax.

Here's the code:

```py
import sqlite3

# Connect to the database
conn = sqlite3.connect('employee.db')
cursor = conn.cursor()

cursor.execute("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS EMPLOYEE")
# Create table
create_table_query = '''
CREATE TABLE EMPLOYEE (
    Emp_no INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
    E_name TEXT,
    E_address TEXT,
    E_ph_no TEXT,
    Dept_no INTEGER,
    Dept_name TEXT,
    Job_id CHAR(10),
    Salary REAL
);
'''
cursor.execute(create_table_query)

# Display the table schema
cursor.execute("PRAGMA table_info(EMPLOYEE)")
table_schema = cursor.fetchall()
print("Table Schema:")
for column in table_schema:
    print(column)

#2.) Alter table - Change the datatype of JOB_ID from char to varchar
cursor.execute('ALTER TABLE EMPLOYEE ALTER COLUMN Job_id VARCHAR (10);')

# Display the updated table schema
cursor.execute("PRAGMA table_info(EMPLOYEE)")
table_schema = cursor.fetchall()
print("\nUpdated Table Schema: Change the datatype of JOB_ID from char to varchar")
for column in table_schema:
    print(column)

conn.close()
```

The error occurs in Line 31 `cursor.execute('ALTER TABLE EMPLOYEE ALTER COLUMN Job_id VARCHAR (10);')`

I've tried different ways but still couldn't work:

```py
cursor.execute('ALTER TABLE EMPLOYEE MODIFY COLUMN Job_id VARCHAR (10);')
```

```py
cursor.execute('ALTER TABLE EMPLOYEE ALTER COLUMN Job_id TYPE VARCHAR (10);')
```

```py
cursor.execute('ALTER TABLE EMPLOYEE ALTER COLUMN JOB_ID VARCHAR (10);')
```

We're expecting this output:

```
Updated Table Schema: Change the datatype of JOB_ID from char to varchar
(0, 'Emp_no', 'INTEGER', 0, None, 1)
(1, 'E_name', 'TEXT', 0, None, 0)
(2, 'E_address', 'TEXT', 0, None, 0)
(3, 'E_ph_no', 'TEXT', 0, None, 0)
(4, 'Dept_no', 'INTEGER', 0, None, 0)
(5, 'Dept_name', 'TEXT', 0, None, 0)
(6, 'Job_id', 'VARCHAR(10)', 0, None, 0)
(7, 'Salary', 'REAL', 0, None, 0)
```

Answer (score 2):

Sqlite has limited `ALTER TABLE` capabilities. You can `ADD` or `REMOVE` a column, but not alter it ([source](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_altertable.html)).

Answer (score 0):

Does it help to add the *type* keyword to the statement?

```
cursor.execute('ALTER TABLE EMPLOYEE ALTER COLUMN Job_id TYPE VARCHAR (10);')
```

See [How to alter a column's data type in a PostgreSQL table?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7162903/how-to-alter-a-columns-data-type-in-a-postgresql-table)

Comment: How would this help? The question is about SQLite, not Postgresql.