# What kind of date type I should use for phone number and graduation year(the only year)?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I created the database called "School" and a table, "students".
As for students, I cannot insert a data of a graduation year since I set a wrong way of dataset. I should have set it as "year", but I did "date". After I notice this, I have been trying to change the data type of graduation_year, but errors always come out. Would you mind telling me another way of changing the data type? The first code shows the creation of the table, student and the second shows my attainment to change the data type for the column "graduation_year".

```
CREATE TABLE students(
    student_id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
    first_name VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    last_name VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    homeroom_number INTEGER CHECK(homeroom_number > 0),
    phone INTEGER UNIQUE NOT NULL,
    email VARCHAR(50) UNIQUE NOT NULL,
    graduation_year DATE CHECK (graduation_year > '1900-01-01')
)
```

```
ALTER TABLE students
ALTER COLUMN graduation_year year
```

I expect the right code below

Not
`graduation_year DATE CHECK (graduation_year > '1900-01-01') )`

but
`graduation_year year`

Comment: Please tag the relevant RDBMS - is it actually SQL Server or PostgreSQL?

Comment: If it is SQL Server, there is no "year" datatype (at least not in recent versions of SQL Server) - you would be best off just using "smallint", if you are really only ever going to store the 4-digit year

Comment: @Craig It is for PostgreSQL

Comment: please share the error description when you trying alter table
`ALTER TABLE students
ALTER COLUMN graduation_year year`

Comment: I tried the data type "year", but the error came out. I will use smallint instead of using year, then. I found the data type, but wondered if there was anyone more suitable! Thank you so much!

Comment: closed this question.  Thank you for everyone.

Comment: You don't need to add solved to the title... the fact that you accepted an answer is visible everywhere and says the same thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this alter script instead

```
ALTER TABLE students
ALTER COLUMN graduation_year TYPE smallint;
```

This is for your reference:

[How to alter a column's data type in a PostgreSQL table?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7162903/how-to-alter-a-columns-data-type-in-a-postgresql-table)
https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-altertable.html

Comment: Thank you soo much, Heinz!! Appreciate it!

Comment: I am confused. There is no data type `year` in PostgreSQL.

Comment: Yeah. But the idea is adding `TYPE` before designated data type